# Animate mesh by Geonodes and noise texture

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

How I can animate my object (separated mesh) with geonodes and noise texture?
[image]

[image]

Comment: May I suggest that you include a blend file so that someone can explain using your initial file?  It will get you a better, quicker response.  If there are other things in your file you don't want to share, submit a copy with only what we see in your screencapture.

Comment: Please be so kind and specify your question, because the question "How I can animate my object (separated mesh) with geonodes and noise texture?" simply allows too many answers here.

Comment: On the one hand you show here in the picture a structure, which obviously consists of extruded cubes, and in your example file you have however a SVG inside. So what do you want to do now? Also, in your [other post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270838/) you talk about increasing the scaling from 0-1, but at the same time you talk about reducing the scaling, and in the end they should all be the same. Equal to what? Same as what mesh or what input? I think it would be good if you go into more detail here. Thank you!

Comment: And just briefly, just so you understand what your question is about: You cannot scale individual elements with the node `Transform` the way you want. `Transform` always refers to the whole object and is not applicable to parts of a geometry. So no matter how you twist it: Either you have independent elements (e.g. instances) that you can scale independently with `Scale Instances`, or you use `Set Position` on specific points/edges/faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is combine the number that `Mesh Island` gives you with the seconds of `Scene Time`, and use that as the vector for `Noise Texture`.

Since you have a mesh here that consists of several separate parts, the individual positions of the vertices are moved to a different position with `Set Position`.

However, to make sure that this only happens to the upper faces (I assume you wanted it that way), I create a selection beforehand that only selects these.

[image]

In your concrete example, however, you don't scale anything, but you move it instead, because you can only scale objects independently of each other if they exist individually as instances.

In your case, however, they are not, but you have a mesh here that was created from an SVG graphic.

Applied to this example, the solution looks like this:

[image]

1. Select the upper points and put them into a separate vertex group.
2. In *Geometry Nodes* you can select this vertex group with the node `Named Attribute` and put it as selection into the node `Set Position`.

In this way you move only certain points of your mesh, which is equivalent to scaling individual elements.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: I don't like moving. I need a scale from 0 to 1. So the cubes at the end must have a fixed pre-set height

Comment: @IgorYukhimenko If you move only the top faces, it will be the same result. So please share your blend-file.

Comment: I am shared file

Comment: @IgorYukhimenko And I have updated the answer (and the blend-file).

Comment: I just can't understand one thing. With this approach, how will I get the given height of each element?
These stripes at the end of the animation must be of a strictly specified height. And they should increase in size randomly.
So I don't understand how moving the top edge can solve this problem.

Comment: @IgorYukhimenko The height can be determined by the position. But please be so kind and specify your original question, because the question *"How I can animate my object (separated mesh) with geonodes and noise texture?"* simply allows too many answers here.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of considerations for this one? ...

- *Noise* is smooth. (As opposed to *White Noise*, or *Random Value*.) You might want to see the noise 'flow' through the bars. At the right noise-scale and speed, you can.
- A single row of bars needs only one dimension of noise. (If you wanted the animation to loop, though, you could use 2 dimensions, and go round a circle in it.)

For example, here are some parameters you could expose through the modifier, if your instances are down a line in X:

[image]

[image]

[image]